# RavenDB paging with Skip and Take does not work

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, lucene

I am trying to implement a query on a RavenDB Lucene index and paging the results.

I have the following code:

```
        IDocumentQuery<Post> q = Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Post, Posts_Search>()
            .WhereContains("BodyHtml", query)
            .OrElse()
            .WhereContains("Title", query)
            .AddOrder("Published", true)
            .Skip(4).Take(4);
```

(The last pair of Skip and Take was added for the sake of a simple example).

This query always returns all of the 22 documents that matches my query, not only 4, as I would expect.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you call .ToString() on the query you will get the actual string that is sent over the wire, what is it for your query?

Comment: @Matt, ToString() returns "BodyHtml:net OR Title:net", and it does this both before and after applying Skip/Take. If I do this on Session.Query<Something>, paging works as expected. I wonder if this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was occuring on the latest stable build (206).

I have now downloaded the latest unstable build (251), and with this build, my code works as expected. I guess it was a bug in the version I was using. If I get anything more meaningful insight from my question in the RavenDB group, I will make sure to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here as I don't know RavenDB. But perhaps the Raven provider does not support skip or take.

You could try converting to an IEnumerable after your .AddOrder to verify that. (You would then be using Linq to Objects to Skip and Take, note you would still be getting all your records from the DB first)

```
  ...
  .AddOrder("Published",True)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Skip(4).Take(4);
```

Comment: Skip and Take should be supported, according to documentation and examples. And I really need the paging to happen on the server.

Comment: what does .AddOrder return? is it a Queryable<T> ? (note i was suggesting the .AsEnumerable() as a test rather than a solution, for exactly the reason you mentioned)

Comment: Skip/Take is supported, I only know because I wrote that part ;-)

Comment: Hi @Matt, loved your blog series on building a linq provider. You thinkng of updating the series to .Net 4.0 ?

Comment: sorry I'm not that Matt Warren, you're not the 1st person to make that mistake :-)